# can't assign to property x on y: not an object - Multidimentional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array like this:

```js
var minutes = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  minutes.push(i);
}
var works = [{
  startTime: 80000,
  endTime: 150000
}, {
  startTime: 200000,
  endTime: 400000
}, {
  startTime: 15000,
  endTime: 80000
}, {
  startTime: 300000,
  endTime: 500000
}];
var sumTime = 0;
var tasksByTime = [];
works.forEach((work, i) => {
  tasksByTime.push(i);
  console.log(tasksByTime);
  var difference = work.endTime - work.startTime;
  minutes.forEach((time, j) => {
    console.log(time * 60 * 1000, difference);
    console.log(i, j);
    if (difference > time * 60 * 1000) {
      tasksByTime[i][j] = (work.id);
    }
  });
  sumTime += difference;
});
console.log(tasksByTime);
```

What I want to do, is sort the objects by the difference between `startTime` and `endTime`. But when I try to console log it I get:

> TypeError: can't assign to property 0 on 3: not an object

Here's the full log:

```
Array [ 0 ]
NumbersPanel.js:35
60000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 0 NumbersPanel.js:41
120000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 1 NumbersPanel.js:41
180000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 2 NumbersPanel.js:41
240000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 3 NumbersPanel.js:41
300000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 4 NumbersPanel.js:41
360000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 5 NumbersPanel.js:41
420000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 6 NumbersPanel.js:41
480000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 7 NumbersPanel.js:41
540000 8498 NumbersPanel.js:40
0 8 NumbersPanel.js:41
Array [ [], 1 ]
NumbersPanel.js:35
60000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 0 NumbersPanel.js:41
120000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 1 NumbersPanel.js:41
180000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 2 NumbersPanel.js:41
240000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 3 NumbersPanel.js:41
300000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 4 NumbersPanel.js:41
360000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 5 NumbersPanel.js:41
420000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 6 NumbersPanel.js:41
480000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 7 NumbersPanel.js:41
540000 12580 NumbersPanel.js:40
1 8 NumbersPanel.js:41
Array(3) [ [], 1, 2 ]
NumbersPanel.js:35
60000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 0 NumbersPanel.js:41
120000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 1 NumbersPanel.js:41
180000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 2 NumbersPanel.js:41
240000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 3 NumbersPanel.js:41
300000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 4 NumbersPanel.js:41
360000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 5 NumbersPanel.js:41
420000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 6 NumbersPanel.js:41
480000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 7 NumbersPanel.js:41
540000 12366 NumbersPanel.js:40
2 8 NumbersPanel.js:41
Array(4) [ [], 1, 2, 3 ]
NumbersPanel.js:35
60000 66934 NumbersPanel.js:40
3 0
```

So it kind of works to a the 4th iteration. Why is that?

PS. It's weird but while the code crashes in the browser, it works in the snippet

[image]

If this matters I'm using React. If React is not a valid tag here, please remove it.

Comment: Please add an example of the desired outcome given your `works` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your outmost forEach: you are pushing into `taskByTime` the value of `i` - but `i` is a `Number`, not an `Array`!

So when you later do `taskByTime[i][j]`, first you're retrieving the element at `i` position in `taskByTime`, which is a `Number`, and then treat it as an array - so it doesn't work.

To fix it simply change your first `push`. Not sure if you need to add an empty array:

```
tasksByTime.push([]);
```

Or if you need to add the work:

```
tasksByTime.push(work);
```

I think logic-wise it should work with both, could be one is a bit more performant than the other

Comment: Well that is confusing. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexIronside I still think there is a more elegant solution. Could you provide the example please :) ? So I can update my answer to fit your requirements.. Because the code you provided does not provide the structure you showed in the comment below my answer and I'd like to see how it should look like.

Comment: @trixn One second

Comment: @trixn Actually I don't even have the full logic formed in my head right now. Thank you for the help though